# I get an error xxx has been blocked by CORS policy in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a system that can login with email and password with React.js.
The backend (REST API) has already been completed by the client
The following error message occurred while implementing the code below.
I'm not sure URL of the API received from the client is bad or
the client needs to edit the CORS settings on the backend side?
I was a little unsure, so I asked the question.
Also, if something weird on my code, please give me advice.

The error is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.xxx.com/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The whole code is below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import  { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { apiURL } from './Default';
import logo_image from "../images/logo/logo.png";
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import background from "../images/background/BG.png";
import '../App.css';

import { isLoggedInOn } from "../stores/user";
import { setUserID } from "../stores/user";

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies();
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  
  const getJwt = async (data) =>{

        console.log(data)

        await axios.post(`https://login.xxx.com/login`,
          {
            username:data.email,
            password:data.password,
          },

        )

        .then(function (response) {

          console.log(response.data.access)

          setCookie('accesstoken', response.data.access, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });

          setCookie('refreshtoken', response.data.refresh, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });

          dispatch(isLoggedInOn());

          history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("miss");
            alert("Email or Password is wrong!");
        });
      };

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row mx-auto">
      <div className="col-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
          <div className="row mx-auto logo_image">
            <img className="" src={logo_image} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="login-block">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getJwt)}>
              <input placeholder='Email Address' className='form-control' {...register('email')} />
              <input placeholder='Password' className='form-control' type="password" {...register('password', { required: true })} />
              <Link to={`/`} style={{color: "white"}}>Reset password</Link><br></br>
              <input className='btn btn-block btn-primary col-12' type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="register-block">
            <p style={{color: "white"}}>Don't have an account yet?</p>
            <Link to={`/signup`} className='btn btn-secondary col-12'>Register</Link>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>




  );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: CORS has to be enabled from the backend

Comment: Try to host API with a domain. Since React load in the user browser , API is not available from out of the server. If you have already API with a domain, seems you haven't pointed it in the React frontend

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for when you deploy to serve, but for local development, inside the `package.json` you can set the property `"proxy": "https://login.xxx.com/"` this will remove the CORS error.

```
{
  "name": "flickr-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

Reference [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app)

Comment: Thanks I did it but same error...